# Couldn't add the local workspace in Jenkins under the maven job

Tags: maven, selenium-webdriver, jenkins, pom.xml, junit4

I am trying to run my Selenium-Cucumber-Junit test suite using Jenkins. I created a maven job and gave the path of my pom.xml. But the job is not running successfully and couldn't see my local workspace under the job I created and couldn't add the workspace manually. I have tried a lot but couldn't figure it out by myself. Please suggest any workaround.

[image]

Comment: You Jenkins pipeline code can help show what went wrong.